test bean with @value
I'm trying to test my @Component
@Component 
class Bean1(
private val someRepository:RepositoryOne,
private val someService:ServiceTwo,
@Value("app.env") private val envValue:Long 

my test look like
@ExtendWith(MockKExtension::class)
class Test(){
@MockK
lateinit var someRepository: RepositoryOne
@MockK
lateinit var someService: ServiceTwo
@InjectMockKs
lateinit var instanse: Bean1
  fun Test1(){
    TODO()
   }
}

How i can put some value for envValue in my MockkedBean.
If i use at this i get error:  kotlin.Long = <not able to lookup>)

you can probably use some reflection to set it, something like val property = Bean1::class.declaredMemberProperties.find { it.name == "envValue" } then property?.let { it.isAccessible = true   //newline// it.setter.call(myComponent, "Test Value")}

what is the mockk version?

Mockk version 1.13.3
